# iOS ViewController Tableview Delegate Functions Not Being Called

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a regular ViewController that contains a TableView. I am using storyboards to lay everything out, but none of the TableView delegate functions are being called. Is there something that I need to do to set the ViewController as the delegate for the TableView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the data source and delegate for the table view. Go to the storyboard and ctrl+click on the table view and drag it to the view controller that will be controlling the table view. There a pop will show and you can select it as the data source and delegate.